# Passing shared_ptr to thread

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I have the following code:

```
shared_ptr<A> a;
B b(a);
a.reset(new A());
```

while in class B I create a new thread and wait for **a** to be "ready":

```
B(shared_ptr<A> a) {
    _a = a;
    //create thred here
}

//...

//in thread:
while (_this->_a == NULL) {}
```

The problem is that even after the line *a.reset(new A());* is executed, the thread started in B still thinks that *_this->_a* is empty and never leaves the while loop!

I tried to use *a = make_shared(new A());* or *a = shared_ptr(new A());* - the effect still the same. I also tried to pass **a** as *const reference* - same thing.

Most interesting thing is that when I use a plain pointer and pass a reference to that pointer to class B, everything works fine:

```
A* a;
B b(a);
a = new A();

//...

B(A*& a) {
    _a = a;
    //create thred here
}

//in thread:
while (_this->_a == NULL) {}
//In this case the loop is finished
```

What do I miss here?

**UPDATE (01.05.2014):**
I solved the problem with code like this:

```
typedef shared_ptr<ClassA> ClassAPtr;
typedef shared_ptr<ClassB> ClassBPtr;
typedef shared_ptr<ClassC> ClassCPtr;

//...

ClassAPtr a(new ClassA());
ClassBPtr b( new ClassB() );
b->attachA(a);
a->attachB(b);
ClassCPtr c( new ClassC() );
c->attachB(b);
c->attachA(a);

c->run();
b->run();
a->run();
```

While in each of those classes I have atomic variable _running:

```
atomic<bool> _running;
```

Also I have the following synchronization code in each thread loop:

```
while (
        _this->_a == NULL || !_this->_a->isRunning()
        ||
        _this->_b == NULL || !_this->_b->isRunning()
        )
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
```

Comment: That's not how a shared pointer works, at all.

Comment: @KerrekSB could you please explain a bit further?

Comment: It's hard to see where to begin. Read up on how shared pointers work; you should see where your error lies. Shared pointers share ownership of an object; what you're looking for is more like a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: I know that shared_ptr shares an ownership. How exactly did you see from my code that I don't? And why should I use "pointer to pointer"?

Comment: Well, `reset` gives the shared pointer a new ownee, so that doesn't really make sense for what you're trying to do, whereas a pointer to a (atomic) pointer would.

Comment: @Cruel_Crow: You compare a `std::shared_ptr` to a `A*&`: a pointer and  a reference-to-pointer.  _Thats_ why one works and one doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a *copy* of `shared_ptr<A>` to the instance of `B`. When you assign a new object to `a` by calling `reset`, the copy stored in `b` has no idea this has happened. This is why it never sees the update.

Calling `shared_ptr::reset` makes that instance of the `shared_ptr` relinquish ownership of the managed object, which means decrementing the `use_count` and destroying the object if that instance happens to be the sole owner. If it's not the sole owner, then the other `shared_ptr`s managing that object become responsible for managing its lifetime. In either case, the instance that you invoked `reset` is now free to take ownership of another object that you may have passed as an argument. In your case this is all a bit simpler since there is no object being managed initially, but the same logic applies. The copy stored within `b` is in no way linked to `a` after the call to `reset`.

Say your class `A` implements two member functions, `activate()` and `is_active()`, with obvious functionality. Also assume that constructing an instance of `A` leaves it in a *deactivated* state until you call `activate()`. Then you could solve this problem as follows:

```
auto a = make_shared<A>();
B b(a);
a->activate();

// within the thread
while (!_this->_a->is_active()) {}
```

Even so, you'd need to use some synchronization primitive to a prevent data race. For instance, if `activate()` sets a boolean data member, the type of that member should be `std::atomic<bool>` or `std::atomic_flag`, instead of a plain `bool`. The same applies to any other data members that maybe read from and written to from different threads.

Comment: @Cruel_Crow That could just be because `shared_ptr` is not thread-safe, so your changes are not seen by the second thread. It doesn't sound like you need shared ownership, but something like `atomic<A*>`, or `atomic<unique_ptr<A>>`. Pass a pointer to this atomic type to `B`, which it can then observe.

Comment: Actually, I do need shared ownership. In my program A uses B, B uses A and C uses both of them.

Comment: @Cruel_Crow Regarding my earlier comment, you can't have `atomic<unique_ptr<T>>` since `atomic` can only be used with TriviallyCopyable types. From your most recent description, it sounds like `C` should be the sole owner of both `A` and `B`, and then you can pass around (atomic, if necessary) pointers to each other to `A` and `B`.

Comment: That what I thought to do, but I hoped to use some smart pointer instead of a plain one.

Comment: Please, take a loop at the update in the question. Did I get the idea right?

Comment: @Cruel_Crow Looks like the `_a`, `_b` etc data members should also be `atomic` pointers.

Comment: The code actually works fine... Is it really necessary to use atomic<A*>, atomic<C*>, etc. instead of shared_ptr, while I manually manage synchronization of each class member which is potentially could lead to a data race?

Comment: @Cruel_Crow I missed that those are `shared_ptr`s and not raw pointers. I'm not sure what the right answer is. The reference counting mechanism for `shared_ptr`s will be atomic, so maybe your code's OK? But if I had to make a guess, I'd say it's open to a data race right now because you're assigning the `shared_ptr` from the main thread and reading it in each thread you spawn. You should post a separate question about that specific use.

Answer (score 0):

A `std::shared_ptr` is not thread-safe. You need to use different synchonization mechanisms. `std::future` is an object that can be used to wait for another thread. You can create one using an `std::packaged_task`.

What might be happening is that a local copy is made of the internals of your shared pointer. This cached copy isn't aware of updates in your main memory. The pointer is updated, but this is dependent on which compiler, what optimizations are active and CPU architecture.

Comment: Has nothing to do with caches.  He's making a _copy_ of an object and then waiting for his copy to change.